# Parse xml file in java and convert results to javabean

Tags: java, xml

i would like to know how to parse xml file in java and convert results to javabean from it. Can anyone guide me thanks?

Comment: may be you need to check JaxB http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/index.html

Answer (score 0):

A really simple and convenient way: http://simple.sourceforge.net/

You can find many examples there for using it, too.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB allows you to write an XSD to which your XML file should conform and then generate the java beans automatically. You don't need to hand-code the beans yourselves.

Check out the tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/.